# wildfly and jerseys MultiPartFeature.class

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, wildfly-10

I want to migrate from tomcat to Wildfly 10.1, so I created a web application for testing Jersey rest web service on Wildfly.

when I run the project it shows error according to `MultiPartFeature.class`

this is my `ApplicationConfigure.java`

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfigure extends ResourceConfig {


    public ApplicationConfigure() {

        register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);

        packages(true, "com.example.controllers");

    }

}
```

and this is the error (WildFly log):

```
11:18:13,855 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-webapplcation: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-webapplcation: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1437)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1368)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1290)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2438)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:99)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.util.FeatureContextDelegate.register(FeatureContextDelegate.java:37)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.util.FeatureContextDelegate.register(FeatureContextDelegate.java:12)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature.configure(MultiPartFeature.java:65)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1368)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1290)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:368)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:250)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:113)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RESTEASY003900: Unable to find a public constructor for provider class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createConstructorInjector(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2255)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2244)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addMessageBodyReader(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:806)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1432)
    ... 37 more
```

netbeans log:

```
Deploying /usr/local/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/wildfly-webapplcation-1.0.war
"{
    \"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-webapplcation\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-webapplcation: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RESTEASY003900: Unable to find a public constructor for provider class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide\"},
    \"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:\" => [\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-webapplcation\"],
    \"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => undefined
}"
```

when I remove the `MultiPartFeature.class` it is deployed pretty well.

by the way, this application works on `Tomee` nicely.

what should I do? I need this feature for my uploads api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As application server Wildfly provides its own implementation of JAX-RS specification. Here the framework in play is RESTEasy not Jersey.

So how it can be seen from your log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1437)
```

RESTEasy engine is trying to start Jersey's feature and fail to do so. There is not so much unification in JAX-RS implementations so quite often they are incompatible.

You have two possible solutions

1. Switch from Jersey to RESTEasy. There [multipart support](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/#Multipart) is somewhat different
2. Turn off Wildfly's RESTEasy scanning of your application and start Jersey server internally. There are multiple articles on the internet about it. Not sure which approach will work for your version.

Comment: which one do you recommend? and why?

Comment: I'm not an expert on RESTEasy to be able to compare it to Jersey. The latter is my primary framework. The answer may greatly depend on why you have decided to migrate to application server. Staying with Jersey may be safer, especially when you lack test coverage. Moving to AS without using its features is like migrating from Tomcat to... bloated Tomcat. At the same time using feature from AS reduce your app size, startup time, memory usage and have some other advantages.

Comment: I tried to user RestEasy but..., let me just say I could not communicate with it. thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

I whent through this issue and I managed to force my application using jersey by manually calling a 
`JerseyClientBuilder().build()` instead of `ClientBuilder().build()`.

The jersey client seems to be the default one, so if you have another one defined it will be the one picked by the `ClientBuilder().build()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue when I upgraded Jersey library version from 1.x to 2.x in server as well as client level.

**1. Server level changes:**

In my `web.xml` added the below entries to eliminate the `resteasy` scan from the classpath libraries.

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

in my servlet section added the below providers

```
    <servlet>
         ....
         ....
        <init-param>
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
          <param-value>
            com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider,
            org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
          </param-value>
        </init-param>      
        ....
        ....
    </servlet>
```

**2. Client level changes:**

During my upgrade, I just changed the client related class packages from `com.sun.jersey.api.client` to `org.glassfish.jersey.client` and was in the assumption that all glassfish jersey's default providers will be registered during the client instantiation, rather `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory` was initialized, The primary reason is, I used `Client client = Client.create();` to create client. Also, after the issue, changed the aforementioned client creation to the below snippet which led me to an issue

> Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]] .

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webResource = client.target(url);
ClientResponse response = webResource.path(path).request("application/json")
                                 .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                                 .put(Entity.json(json), ClientResponse.class);

if (response.getStatus() < 200 || response.getStatus() > 299) {
    throw new CustomException("HTTP Status: " + response.getStatus());
}
String responseInString = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

The Json parsing issue is because of the method [`org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation#translate`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/f0e0106dc24663294fdc9d787981c118c2236d99/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.java#L736) where entity read is happening with the message entity input stream as an instance of specified Java type using a `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader` for the types other than javax.ws.rs.core.Response`.

Finally, solved the above issue by completely adopting the Jersey family client classes.

The working client:

```
JerseyClient client = JerseyClientBuilder.createClient()
                                      .register(JacksonFeature.withoutExceptionMappers());
JerseyWebTarget webResource = client.target(url);
Response response = webResource.path(path).request("application/json")
                                .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                                .put(Entity.json(json), Response.class);

if (response.getStatus() < 200 || response.getStatus() > 299) {
    throw new CustomException("HTTP Status: " + response.getStatus());
}
String responseInString = response.readEntity(String.class);
```